# Azure Python Function - Writing a video file to tmp folder is saving file with zero bytes

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure python function that loads the video from Azure blob storage, and saves it locally in tmp folder. In local environment everything works correctly. But when I deploy this code to Azure Function, the file is created but no information is written to it. The file size is 0.

Any pointer?

Here is the code block how I am doing it -

```py
def getBlob(url, fileName, blobName, containerName):
    tempdir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    local_path = os.path.join(tempdir, fName)
    connect_string = "CONNSTRING"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_string)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=containerName, blob=blobName)
    with open(local_path, "wb") as my_file:
         download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
         my_file.write(download_stream.readall())
    isFile = os.path.isfile(local_path) # This says true. File is created
    file_size = os.path.getsize(local_path) # This gives 0 bytes. File is empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It was an issue with wrong container. I spent hours fixing something that was such a silly mistake.